# I want to select an increment counter group by medec field please how to do this and i would like the output will be as below

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select an increment counter group by medec field please how to do this and i would like the output will be as below [image]

```
SELECT @n := @n + 1 as n, Nb, medec, prest, Nompatient, ftt, Categorie 
FROM (SELECT @n := 0, m.nom as medec, s.id as Nb, ft.id as ftt, sv.libelle , m.nom , pr.libelle as prest, p.nom as Nompatient, ct.libelle as Categorie from services sv, medecins m, sejours s, sejourprestations sjp, prestations pr, patients p, categoriepatients ct, factures ft 
WHERE sv.id = s.service_id 
    AND s.medecin_id = m.id 
    AND s.patient_id = p.id 
    AND s.categorie_patient_id = ct.id 
    AND sjp.sejour_id = s.id 
    AND sjp.prestation_id = pr.id 
    AND s.facture_id=ft.id 
    AND day(s.created_at) = day(CURRENT_DATE)) AS ishmael 
GROUP BY n 
ORDER BY medec
```

Comment: Explain what you really want to do with this code.

Comment: what i want to do is please i just attached an image kindly you can see my issue to the image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Luv.png

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SQL window function, for exemple you can have this result with the OVER clause :

```
SELECT COUNT(Nb) OVER (PARTITION BY medec) as n
```

Comment: so please can you specify where to add in my syntax

Comment: No i'm sorry i can't do your job. If you want more specification you can check the MySQL documentation about the OVER clause.